# Is egrep able to output the results of parenthesized subexpressions?

Tags: regex, unix, grep, bsd

Is `egrep` able to output the results of parenthesized subexpressions?

I’m using macOS, and when I checked the man page for grep, it mentioned `re_format(7)`. Checking `man 7 re_format`, I see that it does have support for parenthesized subexpressions and records them in the `pmatch array`.

However, it isn’t clear how to make `egrep` output just the parenthesized subexpressions in groups somehow.

Comment: some `grep` versions have `-o` option to output only matching portion of regex.. but that doesn't require capture groups... you'll have to add sample input lines and expected output... also, is grep the only command you can use? why not use sed/awk/perl etc

Comment: Greetings @Sundeep – `grep` is not the only option but I was curious if it could be done. Looks like I am indeed going to have to use a more specialized language like what you’re referencing.

Comment: Yes. Or no. It all depends what you mean. [edit] your question to show a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output to clarify what it is you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `egrep` is not able to output the results of parenthesized subexpressions.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what youre trying to do (using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match()):

```
$ cat file
aa(bb(cc(dd)(ee)ff)(gg))hh

$ awk '{ while( match($0,/(.*)\(([^)]*)\)(.*)/,a) ) { print ++c, a[2]; $0=a[1] a[3]} print "rest:", $0 }' file
1 gg
2 ee
3 dd
4 ccff
5 bb
rest: aahh
```

Comment: This is cool and I appreciate your efforts, but I just wanted to know if it was possible with `egrep`. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That depends what `it` is. See my comment under your question.

Comment: I’m stuck for time at the moment (thanks for your continued efforts!) but if you search for “parenthesized subexpression” in https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format&sektion=7 then you can see what I’m talking about. I want `grep` to just output those matches.

Comment: You're welcome but you'd be amazed how much less time I have to work on your problem than you do :-). So no I won't be searching for anything or trying to figure out your issue otherwise. See [ask] then do that...

Comment: Haha I believe you  Have a good one and thanks for the kind effort earlier!